# How to convert a textfile into a list after every word

Tags: python, list

[image]

I have a texfile looking like this:

```
K   Alex    Music   15
B   Anna    Soccer  19
U   Franco  Rugby   29 
A   Carmen  Tennis  27
```

---

How do I convert the textfile into a list where each word is one element so it looks like this [K,Alex,Music,15 ...etc]. The problem I find is that the texfile doesn't contain any commas (,) that I could have split the words after. One of the reasons why I need the words in a list is that I need to find a way to organize the order of the 4 word sentences depending on which variable the person that uses the code wants. So for example I have to be able to organize after the age or the order of the names etc.

Comment: You might want to look at the `re` library offered by python and convert multiple spaces into a split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("File.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()
    list = content.split()
```

This should read the whole content and then split by spaces, turning them into a list.

Comment: When I do precisely that the output I get when printing the list is and empty string ['  ']. The problem is that the number of spaces between the words in the textfile varies, you can check the picture I inserted of the textfile

Comment: for me it works perfectly, this is the output:
['K', 'Alex', 'Music', '15', 'B', 'Anna', 'Soccer', '19', 'U', 'Franco', 'Rugby', '29', 'A', 'Carmen', 'Tennis', '27'].
Did you already change content.split(" ") to content.split() ?